# Problema Apache - 2 dominios

Tags: linux, apache, servidor

boa tarde...

Estou tentando configurar 2 dominios em 1 servidor:
_Debian Linux
_Apache2

Criei o seguinte arquivo: pclinx.conf , logo apliquei a2ensite , icou habilitado e reiniciei o apache2.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName www.pclinx.com.br
ServerAlias *.pclinx.com.br
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/pclinx


<Directory />
   Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
   AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/pclinx>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Em /var/www/html/pclinx tem um arquivo index.html .... mais não consigo visualizar o index.

Site: www.pclinx.com.br

Podem me ajudar por favor?

Answer (score 0):

> Você pode tentar assim, em  **VirtualHost** colocar  o IP do Servidor, acesse o log do Apache2 que está no **/var/log/**, para ver que erro ocorre.

```
<VirtualHost IP_DO_SERVIDOR:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName www.pclinx.com.br
ServerAlias *.pclinx.com.br
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/pclinx


<Directory />
   Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
   AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/pclinx>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

> Se precisar de um gerenciador de Hospedagem use o ISPConfig3, script para instalar no Ubuntu: https://gist.github.com/jniltinho/4b50de4a24a162add15f

Answer (score 0):

Acabei de configurar aqui para simular o seu problema. Fiz desta forma:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/pclinx/
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    ServerName www.pclinx.com.br
        <Directory /var/www/html/pclinx/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiView
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Sugiro você apagar o que tentou e por isto ao invés. Caso não consiga fazer funcionar, poste aqui as últimas linhas do seu log do apache.

Não esqueça de reiniciar o apache depois de efetuar a mudança.